# ionic 2/3 : control the opening of splashScreen with LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, ionic2, splash-screen

How to set localStorage value when splash is opened and make a test on the localstorage value to do not open the splash again, I'm using ionic 3 and  I set this configuration on the config.xml :

```
  <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

here is my ionviewdidload function in  home.ts file :

```
ionViewDidLoad(){

    if (localStorage.getItem('splash')=='0') {

      this.tabBarElemen.style.display = 'none'
      setTimeout(() => {
      this.splash = false;
      localStorage.setItem('splash','1');
      this.tabBarElemen.style.display = 'flex';
      }, 2000);  
    }

  }
```

here is the html code of splashscreen :

```
<div id="custom-overlay" [style.display]="splash ? 'flex': 'none'">
    <div class="flb">
        <div class="Aligner-item Aligner-item--top"></div>
        <img class="splash-screen-logo" src="img/logo.svg">
        <div class="Aligner-item Aligner-item-bottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

some help please ! thanks

Comment: Is this the real system splashScreen that is shown when you open the app or is a custom splash you show after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Ionic Native' Splashscreen plugin, you've got full control of showing/hiding your splashscreen.

Example:

```
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

constructor(private splashScreen: SplashScreen) { }

this.splashScreen.show();

this.splashScreen.hide();
```

More info could be found at: [Splashscreen docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/splash-screen/)

Comment: in addition to this you may also have config.xml edits `<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />`